Unable to find code generated for [ObservableProperty]
I am trying to get into App Programming and wanted to learn the basics about MAUI and MVVM.
With the following code:
public partial MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string? text;
}

I'm expecting to see the code generated for that [ObservableProperty] in my project under Dependencies => Analyzers => CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators => CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.ObservableObjectGenerator
but all I have is a message that says:

This generator is not generating files.

I tried to build a whole new project and start all over again. But it didn't work as well.
I checked on correct C# version and CommunityToolkit.Mvvm version.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Your code and project's setup are fine, you're simply looking in the wrong place. The source generator that deals with [ObservableProperty] is CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.SourceGenerators.ObservablePropertyGenerator.
The one you were looking at (ObservableObjectGenerator) deals with [ObservableObject]. For example it'd have generated something if you had the following code instead:
[ObservableObject]
public partial class MainViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string? text;
}

